# awk - processing two files

Tags: awk, gawk

I have two files which I need to compare by some fields:

reference file:

```
42:B:0
43:A:1
44:A:1
45:A:1
```

target file:

```
42:!:1
43:B:0
44:A:1
45:B:2
```

What I need I can already achieve with combined 'while' loop + awk:

```
$ cat reference|while IFS=: read a b c;do awk -F: -va=$a -vb=$b -vc=$c '$1==a{if($2!=b){if($3>c)if($2!="!"){ print a":target has bigger $3("$3">"c") and $2 different ("$2")" } else { print a":target has bigger $3("$3">"c") but $2 disabled ("$2")" }}}' target;done
42:target has bigger $3(1>0) but $2 disabled (!)
45:target has bigger $3(2>1) and $2 different (B)
```

how could I rid of the 'while' loop and process both files in awk directly?

Answer (score 1):

**`paste`** + **`awk`** magic:

```
paste -d':' reference target | awk -F':' \
'$1 == $4 && $2 != $5 && $6 > $3{ 
     if ($5 == "!"){ p = "but"; state = "disabled" }
     else { p = "and"; state = "different" }
     printf "%s:target has bigger $3(%d > %d) %s $2 %s (%s)\n", $1, $6, $3, p, state, $5 
}'
```

The output:

```
42:target has bigger $3(1 > 0) but $2 disabled (!)
45:target has bigger $3(2 > 1) and $2 different (B)
```

---

Bonus **`gawk`** solution (considering that the 1st field value are ordered and unique):

```
awk -F':' \
'NR == FNR{ 
    a[NR][1] = $1; a[NR][2] = $2; a[NR][3] = $3; next 
}
$1 == a[FNR][1] && $2 != a[FNR][2] && $3 > a[FNR][3]{ 
   if ($2 == "!"){ p = "but"; state = "disabled" }
   else { p = "and"; state = "different" }
   printf "%s:target has bigger $3(%d > %d) %s $2 %s (%s)\n", $1, $3, a[FNR][3], p, state, $2 
}' reference target
```

Comment: I don't know about the input data, but it would fail to pick up something that is "disabled" in both reference and target. It would also require the two files to be of the same lengths and sorted the same way. These things are not mentioned by the user, so it may not be an issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda, that's your subjective. It's obvious that both files should correlate by record numbers (the OP said *What I need I can already achieve*), it's obvious from the OP's effort. As you said *I don't know about the input data* - that's right, you don't know

Comment: I thank you both of you, reference file can have more records than target, all other which exist in target but not in reference should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: '
    FNR == NR { c2[$1] = $2; c3[$1] = $3; next }
    !($1 in c2) {
        printf("%d: $1 not found in reference\n", $1)
        next
    }
    $3 > c3[$1] && $2 == "!"    {
        printf("%d: target has bigger $3 (%d>%d) but disabled $2 (%s)\n", $1,$3,c3[$1],$2)
        next
    }
    $3 > c3[$1] && $2 != c2[$1] {
        printf("%d: target has bigger $3 (%d>%d) but different $2 (%s)\n", $1,$3,c3[$1],$2)
    }' reference target
```

This reads the reference file and then the target file.

When reading the reference file (`FNR == NR`), it collects the values of the second and third column in the two arrays `c2` and `c3`.  The index used is the value in the first column.

When reading the target file (`FNR != NR`), it will compare the value in the third column against the saved value in the `c3` array.  It then also compares the the second column against `!` or against the saved second column from the reference file in `c2`.

The code will also complain with an additional message if the target file's first column is not found in the reference file.

The output, given the data in the question with an added target line (`56:C:9`):

```
42: target has bigger $3 (1>0) but disabled $2 (!)
45: target has bigger $3 (2>1) but different $2 (B)
56: $1 not found in reference
```